# py2exe problems

Tags: python, py2exe

```
c:\python26\setup.py py2exe
```

Trying to run py2exe and when I get to command prompt I run the line above. However as opposed to converting my file it try's to open it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the command above is typed correctly. My Python 2.6 installation on Windows does not have a setup.py file in the location you mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create your own `setup.py` and then run it with py2exe:

```
c:\my_python_scripts>python setup.py py2exe
```

In your `setup.py` you import `distutils`, `py2exe` and show names of your scripts to compile. There is template for it. Then I usually create `.bat` file which compiles my scripts.

Have you read [py2exe tutorial](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial)?